# Redirect rails devise after sign up to specific route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

I am trying to add redirect, so after registration, user should redirect to user edit. But it is redirecting to root link.
 The code is

```
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       redirect_to edit_user_path(resource)
    end
```

This was working fine but now it is redirecting to root route. How can I remove this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The actual path is returned in after_sign_up_path_for method. So redirect_to in it is not needed.

If 'edit_user_path(resource)' exists, then the following should work

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  edit_user_path(resource)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a RegistrationsController to over ride Devise's after_sign_up method. These are good [instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29).
Take into consideration that if the account has to be confirmed by email first, you have to define the after_inactive_sign_up_path_for method. Devise's defaults are the application's root.